# Is there a way to nuke all AWS resources in an AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have an AWS account where multiple EC2 instances, load balancers, target groups, security groups etc are setup by multiple owners. 
We use terraform to set this up but sometimes due to corruption, the state becomes inconsistent. Current mechanism to recover is to manually destroy all resources in that account owned by a particular owner.
Is there an easy way to nuke all resources in an AWS account belonging to a particular owner?

Answer (score 42):

There is no way to delete all resources in an account **owned by a particular user** but there **is a way to delete all resources in an account**.

You can use [aws-nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke) which was created somewhat out of the same use case you described.

1. At first, you need to set an [account alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html) for your account.
2. You must create a [config file](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke#usage).
3. Then you can list down all resources that will be deleted using the following command:

   aws-nuke -c config/nuke-config.yml --profile aws-nuke-example
4. Add --no-dry-run option to permanently delete all resources in the same command.
5. There are also multiple filter options available such as *target*, *resource type*, *exclude*, etc. that you can leverage to suit your needs.

Comment: If you used tags for all resources and tagged by user, this could provide a method to delete resources by a user.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing resources by aws-nuke is not yet supported.

Answer (score 7):

Agree with the other answer that there is no easy way delete orphan resources.

But I see the original issue is that the terraform state is corrupted. 
You can checkout the [terraform import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) feature which lets you generate state file from aws resources. In that way you can connect your config to resources again.

Answer (score 3):

Use Terraformer to import all resources into terraform configuration then do whatever you want:

terraformer import aws --resources="*"

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer

Take care of your state file lock f.e. by using dynamodb & enable s3 versioning.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: actually, that's also no.  There's no built-in capabillity for this.

The case you're describing is not within the bounds of typical AWS usage... destroying everything in an account -- *usually* -- should not be easy.

Of course, you *could* script it, fairly trivially, by wrapping calls to aws-cli to custom code to iterate through the resources and generate additional requests to destroy them... but if you do, lock that code away, since such capability is inherently dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete all your resources you created, you'll need to automate, see a sample here:

## Creation

https://github.com/jouellnyc/AWS/tree/master/create_aws_vpc2

## Deletion

https://github.com/jouellnyc/AWS/blob/master/create_aws_vpc2/delete_lb_and_vpc.sh

## Other

I've had some success with cloud nuke (played around for a few min; not in depth):

https://github.com/gruntwork-io/cloud-nuke

Comment: The first two links do not exist anymore.

Comment: Can't edit because queue is full but here are the two dead links:
https://github.com/jouellnyc/AWS/tree/master/blue_green/aws-cli/create_aws_vpc2
https://github.com/jouellnyc/AWS/blob/master/blue_green/aws-cli/del.iam.sh

Idk how useful these are, just thought I'd find the dead links.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is any state forward way to do it but to check if you have any active resources in your account, do the following:

1. Open the Billing and Cost Management console.
2. Choose Bills in the navigation pane.
3. You can see the charges incurred by different services in the Bill details by service section.
4. You can see the charges incurred in different AWS Regions in the Bill details by account section.

*For each service, identify the Regions where the services have incurred charges.
To terminate the identified active resources under different services, do the following:*

1. Open the AWS Management Console.
2. For Find services, enter the service name.
3. After opening the service console, terminate all your active resources. Be sure to check each Region where you have allocated resources.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to nuke all resources in an AWS account
> belonging to a particular owner?

Since you are using Terraform, you can use [Blank Apply](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/blank-apply-destroying-without-terraform-configuration).
It will destroy all the Resources in a state file.

> We use terraform to set this up but sometimes due to corruption, the
> state becomes inconsistent.

It's better to use version control system to avoid drifts and inconsistencies in your state file and use remote states in order to make sure everyone is on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

[cloud-nuke](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/cloud-nuke) works fine for me

### Example (for Mac)

First I checked for the [Billing Dashboard](https://p6li1chk.r.us-east-1.awstrack.me/L0/https:%2F%2Fconsole.aws.amazon.com%2Fbilling%2Fhome%3F%23%2Fbills/1/010001897b64272f-d26ee617-83b0-4437-9432-f500e3f0e69a-000000/fZirQwnLdKj18UrATcnVh6j_dDg=331) to see the line items by region and got each regions

Then on my **terminal**

Install cloud-nuke

```
brew install cloud-nuke ## Install cloud-nuke
```

Delete all resources on selected regions

```
cloud-nuke aws --region ap-south-1 eu-central-1
```

or scan all the regions

```
cloud-nuke aws
```

If **ERROR** "*could not find any enabled regions binary=cloud-nuke version=your_cn_version*"

Add `aws_region = ap-south-1` (or whatever region) on your aws credential config file

`vi ~/.aws/credentials`

```
[user1]
aws_access_key_id = my_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key = my_secret_access_key
aws_region = ap-south-1
```

Do not forget to add the user ("user1" in the example above) to your Admin group if you have created one or use your default aws admin user

Answer (score 0):

if the issue is a corrupted terraform state, perhaps storing the state in a versioned S3 bucket would help reduce the impact of that.